# How to display Message on latest item in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want display badge in latest item on `recyclerview` and after clicking on it, its visibility is gone. Please help me

[image]

My code is here:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {

    SubCategory_Model_List dataAdapterOBJ =  dataAdapters.get(position);

    if(position==dataAdapters.size()-1){
        // here goes some code
        //  callback.sendMessage(Message);
        Viewholder.triangleLabelView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }




    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(dataAdapterOBJ.getImageUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.default_placeholder)
            .into(Viewholder.imageView);

    Viewholder.ImageTitleTextView.setText(dataAdapterOBJ.getImageTitle());

}
```

Comment: you can set isNew Flag in your model and can change its value on click and notify your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

The logic written by you is fine it should work all you need to do is to add else block and write like

```
else {
Viewholder.triangleLabelView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

and just add an `onclicklistener` in the

```
viewholder.item.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
add your visibility code over here.
please manage your logic.
})
```

Comment: You can ask for a code from server and maintain that, to maintain locally you can save the id of the item in a hashset and save it in preferences and then at the time of creating the view you can check it. It will work fine, but the better approach is to save a field on the server corresponding to the item you clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a `MessageModel` and in this **class** you have some property like:

```
class MessageModel{
  String body;
  int itemId;
  boolean isNew;
}
```

You have **messageList** in your **adapter**. So when you get new message before adding in your adapterList you have to update your new **messageModel**

Think in your activity/fragment class you get new message Like:

```
@ovveride
onGetNewMessage(MessageModel message){
  message.setNew(true);
  mAdapter.addItem(message);
  notifyDataSetChnaged();
}
```

Now in your adapter class `onBindViewHolder` section you have to update your UI like:

```
if(message.isNew()){
  // view will be visible
}else{
  // view will be gone
}
```

Now **Last things** is to update **message** as old. So when you click your message you still have **messageModel** reference in your adapter class. add below things in your `onCLick` method.

```
message.setNew(false);
notifyItemChanged(position);
```